# Spring boot ConstraintViolationException return HashMap with field name and message

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, exception, hashmap

For ConstraintViolationException I want to return HashMap<String,String> with fieldName and message
I wrote something like this:

```
@ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
ResponseEntity<HashMap<String,String>> handleConstraintViolation(ConstraintViolationException e) {
    Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> constraintViolations = e.getConstraintViolations();

    Set<String> errorName = new HashSet<>(constraintViolations.size());
    Set<String> messages = new HashSet<>(constraintViolations.size());

    messages.addAll(constraintViolations.stream()
            .map(violation -> String.format("%s", violation.getMessage())).toList());

    errorName.addAll(constraintViolations.stream()
            .map(violation -> String.format("%s", StreamSupport.stream(violation.getPropertyPath().spliterator(), false).reduce((first, second) -> second).orElse(null))).toList());

    HashMap<String,String> errors = new HashMap<>();
    errors.put(errorName.toString(), messages.toString());

    return new ResponseEntity<>(errors, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

and this returns:

```
[producent, name, description, image]
:[type correct productent, type correct product image, type correct desc, type correct image]
```

I want it to return:

```
producent : "type correct productent",
name : "type correct image",
description : "type correct desc",
image : "type correct image"
```

i dont have idea how i can do it, can someone help with that?

Answer (score 1):

You want to get several keys in map, but just add one.

Try this:

```
@ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
ResponseEntity<HashMap<String, String>> handleConstraintViolation(ConstraintViolationException e) {
    Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> constraintViolations = e.getConstraintViolations();

    HashMap<String, String> errors = new HashMap<>();

    constraintViolations.forEach(violation ->
            errors.put(
                    violation.getPropertyPath().toString(),
                    violation.getMessage()));

    return new ResponseEntity<>(errors, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```